# CoreXY with 8 bit board problems

Tags: firmware, ramps-1.4, arduino-mega-2650, corexy

I know that CoreXY kinematics is very complex and hard to calculate for the firmware making it better to use a 32-bit board. For some reason, I can't use any 32-bit board. What problems will occur if I use an 8-bit board like Arduino Mega with a CoreXY 3D printer?

Everything that I wrote in this question about hard kinematic calculations was referenced from this video, [HyperCube 3D Printer 8-Bit Speed Wall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySqj3gPqfrs), by Tech2c (the designer and builder of hypercube). After watching the video I doubted using an 8-bit board.

Comment: How is corexy hard to calculate? Motor motions should just be sum/difference. Delta on the other hand has nontrivial math.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Tech2c (designer of hypercube) says in [his video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySqj3gPqfrs)

Comment: I'm not convinced at his explanation for the problem. There are a lot of print quality problems in that video.

Comment: Just my 2 cents; that 8-bit board is a dead-end for you. Find a 32-bit solution you like, and keep pushing those boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an 8-bit controller board for a CoreXY kinematics 3D printer. The calculations are not so complicated opposed to those for a Delta.

---

*My Hypercube Evolution uses a RUMBA controller board that hasn't failed me past years.*

Comment: I also want to build a modified hypercube but after watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySqj3gPqfrs) video by Tech2c (inventor of hypercube), I doubted using an 8-bit board.

Answer (score 1):

CoreXY should not require calculations which can slow down a board. Also, a normal Marlin becomes CPU limited often before 100 mm/s on 8 bit boards due to arc interpolation and other processing.

However, if you use Klipper which runs on a Raspberry Pi, 8 bit boards are rarely a limiting factor. I could print at 100 mm/s on mine with only 30% CPU utilisation and without slowdowns of any kind.

See

and

Comment: what about marlin 2?

Comment: @MahanLameie I doubt it will be more cpu efficient than Marlin 1. I don't remember "speed" being one of the improvements.